# Requiring the isomorphism between two FOL interpretations to be a bijection when proving they are elementary equivalent

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Assume we have a formula $F$ with $k$ free variables of some signature, and we also have two isomorphic interpretations $M_1$ and $M_2$ of that signature with $\alpha$ being the corresponding isomorphism. Let's prove
$$
\forall m_1, \dots, m_k : M_1 \models F(m_1, \dots, m_k) \iff M_2 \models F(\alpha(m_1), \dots, \alpha(m_k)),
$$
which is a slightly more generic claim, but would allow us to prove the original one by induction on the structure.

1. If $F$ is an atomic formula, then the claim follows from the fact that isomorphisms preserve predicates and functions.
2. If $F$ is a logical combination of one (using $\lnot$) or two ($\lor, \land, \rightarrow$) formulas, then it follows easily from the inductive hypothesis.
3. $\forall$ is expressible via $\exists$, so we proceed straight to that.
4. If $F(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n)$ is $\exists \xi G(\xi, \xi_1, \dots, \xi_n)$: this is the interesting part. Let's fix $m_1, \dots, m_k$ and consider two subcases:

   1. If $M_1 \models \exists \xi F(\xi, m_1, \dots, m_k)$, then, well, there exists some $m$ such that $M_1 \models F(m, m_1, \dots, m_k)$, and by the inductive hypothesis $M_2 \models F(\alpha(m), \alpha(m_1), \dots, \alpha(m_k))$, so $M_2 \models \exists \xi F(\xi, \alpha(m_1), \dots, \alpha(m_k))$.
   2. If $M_1 \not\models \exists \xi F(\xi, m_1, \dots, m_k)$, assume still $M_2 \models \exists \xi F(\xi, \alpha(m_1), \dots, \alpha(m_k))$, and $m'$ is the value of $\xi$ that makes it true. Since $\alpha$ is an isomorphism, then there exists $\alpha^{-1}(m')$, and by the inductive hypothesis $M_1 \models F(\alpha^{-1}(m'), m_1, \dots, m_k)$, contradicting the claim.

One might note that we haven't really used that $\alpha$ is an isomorphism. Instead, we have only used its surjectivity, which brings two questions:

1. Is this proof correct?
2. If it is, can the surjectivity requirement also be dropped as the injectivity is? The claim looks symmetrical, so it would be surprising if it couldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's identify the issue first, and then try to figure out where the omission occurs.

We want to argue that $\alpha$ preserves all formulas. In particular, this means that somewhere along the line we'll need to show *(something which implies)* that $\alpha$ preserves the formula "$\neg x=y$." But clearly this is equivalent to the injectivity of $\alpha$. So we can see that there must in fact be a gap somewhere in your argument, since in order to show that $\alpha$ preserves all formulas we must use injectivity somewhere.

---

OK, so where's the gap?

As written, I would say you need to be more explicit at (2). Specifically, the *negation* case is important: think about e.g. "$\neg x=y$" (and the relation between preserving this and being injective). So technically you've given the correct "shape," but the injectivity assumption on $\alpha$ is buried in behind the word "easily."

Another option would be to be more explicit at (1). Maybe by "preserves atomic formulas" you mean "preserves *and reflects* atomic formulas," or equivalently "preserves atomic *and negated atomic* formulas." In this case you will need to actually give an argument: while preservation of atomic formulas is built into the hypotheses (other than injectivity) on $\alpha$, the *reflection* of atomic formulas isn't.

Either way, something needs to happen to cover the negated atomic case; this isn't present in your proof as written, and accounts for the apparent unnecessity of injectivity.

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but why? In the negation case $F(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n) = \lnot G(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n)$, and $M_1 \models \lnot G(m_1, \dots, m_n) \iff M_1 \not\models G(m_1, \dots, m_n) \iff M_2 \not\models G(\alpha(m_1), \dots, \alpha(m_n)) \iff M_2 \models \lnot G(\alpha(m_1), \dots, \alpha(m_n))$, where the first and last equivalences are by definition of truthfulness in an interpretation, and the middle one is by the induction hypothesis.

Comment: @0xd34df00d It depends on exactly how you phrase the base case. What you've written is just that $\alpha$ *preserves* atomic formulas, but you also want it to *reflect* atomic formulas. (Or, maybe by "preserves" you mean "preserves in both directions.") The point is that when it comes time to argue that $\alpha$ preserves "$x\not=y$" (or if you prefer, reflects $x=y$) then you need the injectivity of $\alpha$.

Comment: It might be easier to start at the beginning: do you see why, in order to argue that $\alpha$ preserves $x\not=y$, we will need to know that $\alpha$ is injective?

Comment: @0xd34df00d I've edited my answer to be clearer; let me know if this doesn't improve things and I'll further edit or revert as preferred.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now, thank you for the clarification! Yes, I meant "preserves and reflects", so that the implication in both directions holds (sorry, the book I'm using is written in another language, so I might be translating incorrectly). Further, your argument indeed shows that this essentially requires $\alpha$ to be injective, but here you seem to assume the interpretations are normal — or, in other words, that $=$ is interpreted as a match between two elements. That wouldn't be necessarily the case for non-normal interpretations, would it?

Comment: @0xd34df00d I'm not sure what you mean by "non-normal interpretation." "$=$" is always considered a binary relation symbol; moreover, in all modern presentations of first-order logic it's also considered a *logical* symbol (= present regardless of the language) and required to be interpreted as genuine equality. In the absence of equality, you in fact do not require injectivity a priori. For example, consider the empty language in FOL without equality; then *any* surjective function from one structure in this language to another satisfies your principles (cont'd)

Comment: since the only formulas are $\top$, $\perp$, and trivial variations of those (e.g. "$\forall x\exists y\top$").

Comment: Less trivially, suppose we have an arbitrary relation language $\Sigma$ and a $\Sigma$-structure $\mathcal{A}$. We can produce a "thick" version of $\mathcal{A}$ - call it $\mathcal{A}^+$ - by duplicating elements: the domain $A^+$ of $\mathcal{A}^+$ is $A\times\mathbb{N}$, and the interpretation is given by $R^{\mathcal{A}^+}((a_1, k_1), ..., (a_n, k_n))\iff R^\mathcal{A}(a_1,..., a_n)$ for each $n$-ary $R\in\Sigma$ (note that this would be much more complicated with function symbols). Now any "block-preserving" self-surjection from $\mathcal{A}^+$ is "FOL$\setminus\{=\}$"-elementary.

Comment: That explains it! The book I'm using considers `=` as a binary predicate, but it always points out explicitly whenever `=` is interpreted as equality.

Comment: @0xd34df00d Ah. What book are you using, out of curiosity?

Comment: Not sure if the reference would be useful since it's in Russian, but it's https://www.mccme.ru/free-books/shen/shen-logic-part2-2.pdf , based on lectures of Moscow State University's math department.